# Extract schema of nested JSON object

Tags: json, nested, key, jq

Let's assume this is the source json file:

```
{    
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 12,
    "visits": {
        "2017-01-25": 3,
        "2016-07-26": 4,
        "2016-01-24": 1
    }
}
```

I want to get:

```
[
  "age",
  "name",
  "visits.2017-01-25",
  "visits.2016-07-26",
  "visits.2016-01-24"
]
```

I am able to extract the keys using: `jq '. | keys' file.json`, but this skips nested fields. How to include those?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your input, the invocation:

```
jq 'leaf_paths | join(".")'
```

produces:

```
"name"
"age"
"visits.2017-01-25"
"visits.2016-07-26"
"visits.2016-01-24"
```

If you want to include "visits", use `paths`.  If you want the result as a JSON array, enclose the filter with square brackets: [ ... ]

If your input might include arrays, then unless you are using jq 1.6 or later, you will need to convert the integer indices to strings explicitly; also, since `leaf_paths` is now deprecated, you might want to use its def.  The result:

```
jq 'paths(scalars) | map(tostring) | join(".")'
```

#### allpaths

To include paths to null, you could use `allpaths` defined as follows:

```
def allpaths:
  def conditional_recurse(f):  def r: ., (select(.!=null) | f | r); r;
  path(conditional_recurse(.[]?)) | select(length > 0);
```

Example:

```
{"a": null, "b": false} | allpaths | join(".")
```

produces:

```
"a"
"b"
```

#### all_leaf_paths

Assuming jq version 1.5 or higher, we can get to `all_leaf_paths` by following the strategy used in builtin.jq, that is, by adding these definitions:

```
def allpaths(f):
  . as $in | allpaths | select(. as $p|$in|getpath($p)|f);

def isscalar:
  . == null or . == true or . == false or type == "number" or type == "string";

def all_leaf_paths: allpaths(isscalar);
```

Example:

```
{"a": null, "b": false, "object":{"x":0} } | all_leaf_paths | join(".")
```

produces:

```
"a"
"b"
"object.x"
```

Comment: I recognized, that both (`path`and `leaf_paths`) ignores fields that have a value like `null` or `false`. Any idea how to include those?

Comment: Your "allpaths"-edit looks promising, but sadly this one does not seem to work as expected. It actually outputs the full file, including the attribute's values.

Comment: After understanding that I just need to add your custom function definitions to a ~/.jq file, it all works like a charm. Would love to give you a second upvote!

Comment: You don't have to add the functions to ~/.jq -- you could, for example, simply include them in whichever file you specify with the -f option on the command line.  Thanks for the virtual second upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I wrote a structural-schema inference engine that
produces simple structural schemas that mirror the JSON documents under consideration,
e.g. for the sample JSON given here, the inferred schema is:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "age": "number",
  "visits": {
    "2017-01-25": "number",
    "2016-07-26": "number",
    "2016-01-24": "number"
  }
}
```

This is not exactly the format requested in the original posting, but
for large collections of objects, it does provide a useful overview.

More importantly, there is now a complementary validator for
checking whether a collection of JSON documents matches a structural
schema.  The validator checks against schemas written in
[JESS](https://bitbucket.org/pkoppstein/jess/) (JSON Extended Structural Schemas), a superset of the simple
structural schemas (SSS) produced by the schema inference engine .

(The idea is that one can use the SSS as a starting point to add
more elaborate constraints, including recursive constraints,
within-document referential integrity constraints, etc.)

For reference, here is how one the SSS for your sample.json
would be produced using the ["schema" module](https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed):

```
jq 'include "schema"; schema' source.json > source.schema.json
```

And to validate source.json against a SSS or ESS:

```
JESS --schema  source.schema.json  source.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want but it doesn't return the data in an array, but it should be an easy modification:

https://github.com/ilyash/show-struct

you can also check out this page:
https://ilya-sher.org/2016/05/11/most-jq-you-will-ever-need/